# For what values of k is the vector u in the span of the columns of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, span

Let $$u = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\1 \\-1 \end{pmatrix}$$ 
and let$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&1 \\1&1&0 \\0&1&k \end{pmatrix}$$

For what values of k is the vector u in the span of the columns of A?

Here is my work so far:
$$Au = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&1&-1 \\1&1&0&1 \\0&1&k&-1 \end{pmatrix}$$$$Au = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&1&-1 \\0&1&-1&2 \\0&1&k&-1 \end{pmatrix}$$$$Au = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&1&-1 \\0&1&-1&2 \\0&0&k+1&-3 \end{pmatrix}$$

I've reduced it as much as I can, but I'm stuck at this point. Does this mean that k can be equal to -4?

Comment: Here is the check. Use $k=-4$ and use your TI to find out if the given vector is in the span of the columns of the matrix. If you get a unique solution, then you know you did it right.

Comment: That is not really a "solution" to this problem though; $k = 4$ will happen to give such a matrix, but there are *many* other such values of $k$. (in fact, there is only one "bad" value of $k$ and it has nothing to do with $\pm 4$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall what we're trying to do here: the vector $u$ is in the span of the columns of $A$ if there is an $x$ such that $Ax = u$. Under other circumstances you might already know all the entries of $A$ (i.e. there is no $k$ to investigate), and you would write down the augmented matrix $(A\vert u)$ (as you have done here), and then row-reduce.

What is the significance of that process? Why do you want to get $1$s on the diagonal? (what would that tell you about $x$?) What is the significance of a $0$ on the diagonal?

Answer (score 0):

$(-1, 1, -1) = x (1, 1, 0) + y (0, 1, 1) + z (1, 0, k) $

\begin{equation*}
 \left\{\begin{aligned}
-1 = x 1 + y 0 + z 1 \\
1 = x 1 + y 1 + z 0 \\
-1 = x 0 + y 1 + z k
 \end{aligned}
 \right.
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
 \left\{\begin{aligned}
-1 - x &= z(x) \\
1 - x &= y(x) \\
-1 &= y + z k = 1-x + (-1-x) k
 \end{aligned}
 \right.
\end{equation*}

$- \frac{x-2}{x + 1} = k(x)$